# How to prevent database model built by DbModelBuilder from connecting to database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to unit test Expression's support using a SQL Server `DbContext`. I was lucky to find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072304/is-it-possible-to-test-whether-a-given-expression-can-be-converted-to-sql-witho) with a very informative answer by Arthur Vickers. Unfortunately, I'm having some troubles with the implementation.

I've created a simple test app with autogenerated `DbContext` from a database (I have only added a constructor that takes `DbCompiledModel` as argument):

```
public partial class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TestDbContext() : base("name=TestDbContext")
    {
    }

    public TestDbContext(DbCompiledModel model) : base(model)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is that my code still connects to database and prints data from it:

```
var dbModelBuilder = new DbModelBuilder();
dbModelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().HasEntitySetName("Foos");
var model = dbModelBuilder.Build(new DbProviderInfo("System.Data.SqlClient", "2012"));
var compiledModel = model.Compile();

Database.SetInitializer<TestDbContext>(null);

using (var context = new TestDbContext(compiledModel))
{
    foreach (var foo in context.Foos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Name);
    }
}
```

I guess, that context takes database name from connection string in my `app.config` file (but why, if I am not passing it?). I've tried to remove database name ("initial catalog" param) from this connection string and my code printed no `Foo`'s. I thought, that it was the solution, but then I tried to write and save new `Foo` entity to context:

```
context.Foos.Add(new Foo() { Name = "Bar" });
context.SaveChanges()
```

Next time when I executed the code this entity was printed. SQL Server Management Studio doesn't see any new databases or this entity in the old one and `context.Database.Connection.Database` was an empty string, so it looks like Entity Framework created a database with empty name (is it even possible?) and wrote data to it.

So, is there any way to prevent context from connecting to database or creating new one? My goal is to at least run `context.Foos.Where(expression).ToList()` without connecting to the database and see whether there will be an exception because expression can not be converted to a SQL query.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Here is my `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                  requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="TestDbContext" 
             connectionString="data source=INSPIRON;initial catalog=TestDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like I misunderstood the way of testing proposed in [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13072304/is-it-possible-to-test-whether-a-given-expression-can-be-converted-to-sql-witho). I made some experiments and found out that both iterating through `context.Foos.Where(expression)` with `foreach` and calling `context.Foos.Where(expression).ToString()` will make Entity Framework check `expression` for ability to convert it to SQL query and will create database if it doesn't exist.

But after calling:

```
Database.SetInitializer<TestDbContext>(null);
```

`context.Foos.Where(expression).ToString()` will still check `expression` and throw exception, if `expression` is not correct, but it will not create database. Iterating through `context.Foos.Where(expression)` with `foreach` even with correct `expression` will throw exception because of inability to create database.

So, yes, it is possible to test whether `expression` is supported by Entity Framework without actually creating database or connecting to existing one, but this can be done only by calling 'ToString()', which returns SQL query or throws exception. Trying to iterate through entities with `foreach` will anyway connect to database or throw exception, so it is not suitable for this kind of testing. And this was my mistake.

Maybe, all these was obvious enough, but not for me, so, I hope, my answer may help somebody in the same situation.